# How to install libcc1.so from cross gcc to target-dependent location?

Tags: linux, installation, gcc

So I am packaging and installing gcc for an uncommon target. By default all files (excluding docs) have the target name in their full path. But libcc1.so.0.0.0 and symlinks to it are installed at /usr/lib, (with `--prefix=/usr`, of course) having a conflict with the native complier. In order to install them to a target-dependent path, I specified `--libdir=/usr/lib/target_name` but the files get installed to /usr/lib/lib. This is because libcc1/Makefile specify `cc1libdir = $(libdir)/$(libsuffix)`, while libcc1/configure define `libsuffix` to be `../lib` (in my case; it may also be something like `../lib32` in some configurations so that the libs can be installed to the correct location even if `libdir` has the default value `$PREFIX/lib`)

Perhaps more files are affected in a full installation, but many of the libraries are not suppprted by my target ans are not installed.

I can work this around by manually edit Makefile.am or Makefile.in in directory libcc1 (not tested yet), or use `--libdir=/usr/lib/target_name/dummy` (works). But neither seems nice. The former need manual work whenever updating (am I worrying unnecessarily?). The latter creates confusing deep paths (/usr/lib/target_name/dummy/gcc/target_name/version_number).

Can anyone suggest a better workaround, or even better, a solution?

Comment: Examples, building gcc to "All gcc files in one directory" https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1j7qE9YKTT313B5VBg3kevzCNiykGkonO?usp=sharing ... Results 3 - 9 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47175706/how-to-install-gcc-4-9-2-on-rhel-7-4/47189915#47189915

Comment: @KundLarsen Thanks, maybe it is a good ides to put all gcc files in one directory.